# Should i lock my machine adapter while send packet if i am using several threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, packets, pcap.net

I am using `Pcap.Net` to transmit packet through my machine adapter, i some cases i am read packets from several files in the same time using `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property that can be changed.
So i wonder if i need to lock the object that sent this packet..

This is how my main send the packets:

```
// Open the my device
using (PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))                                                        
{
    Packet packet;

    // Read packet from file
    while (inputCommunicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok)
    {
       // Send packet
       communicator.SendPacket(packet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of WinPcap, I believe that if you don't use the same `PacketCommunicator` in two threads in parallel, you should be fine.